# Clone select option problem

Tags: jquery, select

Consider the following HTML :

```
<div class="list">
<select>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
</select>
```

And Javascript :

```
  var s_m = $("select option[value='one']");
  var sec_mark = s_m.clone();
  console.log(sec_mark.html());
```

I obtained simply `1` text as a result. How can get full option html like `<option value="one">1</option>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this -

```
var s = s_m.clone().wrap('<select></select>').parent().html();
```

That should get the full outer html of the option element, there are further techniques explained in this question - [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)